# Uniformly Most Powerful

Tags: statistical-inference

Let X1;X2; : : : ;X10 denote a random sample of size 10 from a population
which has an exponential distribution with parameter ;  > 0, i.e. with
pdf
f(x) =


e x if x  0;
0 otherwise.
(a) Find the Uniformly Most Powerful Test (UMP) test of size  = 0:01
for testing
H0 :  = 1
against H1 :  = 2:
(b) Suppose the sample selected have values
0:24; 0:34; 0:12; 0:19; 0:18; 0:68; 0:03; 0:70; 0:07; 1:31:
Use this sample to test H0 against H1 at level  = 0:01.
(c) To test
H0 :   1
against H1 :  > 1
based on a random sample of size n = 10, the following critical
region is prescribed:
R = f(x1; x2; : : : ; x10) :
Σ10
i=1
xi  1:5g:
(i) Derive and sketch the power function () of this test.
(ii) Give an approximate value for the size of this test.
(iii) Is this test unbiased? Exp

Comment: Can you convert that to legible?